# Any TNEF file parsing/decoding library in C# available to use in Windows store app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, outlook, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to port existing C library as WinRT component, but it's not working as I must be doing some mistake, I am totally unaware about C++/C dev in Visual Studio. Please anyone help to port existing C lib to C# or help to develop WinRT component from it.

---

Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format or TNEF is a proprietary email attachment format used by Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Exchange Server. An attached file with TNEF encoding is most often named winmail.dat or win.dat. It consists of email body, subject & attachments.

I've searched a lot and found two relevant solution. [One is in C language](http://www.pldaniels.com/opentnef/), that I don't want. [Other solution](http://mailutilities.codeplex.com) (I'm not sure though) is not compatible with WinRT.

So anyone know any C# library by which, I can decode the Winmail.dat file and extract the attached file and other data. I want to consume that lib in C#/XAML WinRT app.

Comment: For the second solution, since you have the source code, what is preventing you from fixing whatever Windows 8 incompatibility it might have?

Comment: I tried that lib with WinForm app, it didn't work. I am not sure if it can decode TNEF file.

Comment: @Xyroid What specific problem are you facing while porting the C code to create a WinRT component?

Comment: I am totally unaware about C++ dev, I just copy pasted all the code from lib to VS project. I was damn sure it's not gonna work but then also I tried.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently written a completely open source (MIT licensed) version of Microsoft's [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ContentTypes.Tnef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.data.contenttypes.tnef(v=exchg.150)) namespace TNEF API in [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) which is available via NuGet.

You can view the documentation for my implementation here: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/N_MimeKit_Tnef.htm

The only difference is the namespace. My implementation uses MimeKit.Tnef instead of Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ContentTypes.Tnef.